# In Unity is it possible to automatically restart an exe after a crash?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game is due to be demoed at a show and although we're confident there are no crash bugs we need a way to make the executable automatically restart if it does encounter a crash just as fail safe.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this via unity, detect that any crash occured or should I do it via a .bat file?

The build will be run on Windows machines at the demo.

Comment: Simple logic dictates that what you want is impossible, since in order for Unity to be able to do anything, it needs to be running, which it isn't anymore, when the game has crashed.

Comment: Not necessarily, there may be a crash handler where I can detect if a fatal error occurred and then restart. Detecting if something crashed and restarting it isn't impossible at all. Im simply asking if this can be done in unity via something like a crash handler or if I should do this another way external to unity.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking .. if the Unity Standalone exe crashes ... There is no way to catch this inside the same process and restart itself? If by "crashes" you rather mean that Exceptions are thrown or any other error inside of your app so yourself can define what a "chrash" is and what not you might be able to come up with a Unity internal solution e.g. using some `try - catch` blocks and reload the scene...

Comment: Ya its the standalone, I see what you're saying, if the application is already crashed it can't catch and restart itself. There are no known exceptions in the game but running at an event show for 12 hours+ you never know.

I saw in another stackoverflow post I can write a .bat file which checks if the exe is running so thats probably the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from withing Unity. You need to have some external watchdog process